# Iterate through a List Multiple times Cyclically starting from the Matching Index

Tags: python, list, iterator, cycle, slice

I need to do the following in python.  I have a list of strings, `list`, a string to search for, `text`, and variable containing the number of elements to print, `x`.  I want to iterate through `x` no. of consecutive elements of the `list`, wrapping around to the front of `list` if necessary.

First I need to find the first element in `list` that has `text` as a substring.  I will then start with the first element of `list` *after* that matched element, and continue to iterate through a total of `x` consecutive elements of the `list`, wrapping around if necessary.

How would I do this?

```
x = 11
text = "string5"
list = ["string1", "string2", "string3", "string4", "string5", "string6", "string7"]

# not sure what to do here...
for elem in list:
    if text in elem:
        #iterate through list, begin with elem and get the next 11 elements
        #once you've reached string7, start over with string1`
```

In this example I want to end up looking at the following 11 elements:

```
string6
string7
string1
string2
string3
string4
string5
string6
string7
string1
string2
```

Comment: I meant the element after "text". Sorry

Comment: You use `if text in elem`. Is it intentional to search if `ŧest` is present in `elem`, or did you mean to compare the strings,  `if text == elem`?

Comment: @spectras OP is now pretty clear that he is looking for a substring: "_first element in list that has text as a substring_"

Comment: Then not only is your answer the one with best style, but it's also the only one that actually does what he wants.

Comment: No, i don't want to compare the strings. I'm looking for a substring. It's intended.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**For our problem data:**

```
x = 11 #no. of elements to get
text = 'string5' #text to search in elements of list
lst = ['string1', 'string2', 'string3', 'string4', 'string5', 'string6', 'string7'] 
n = len(lst) 

# index of required text
i = lst.index(text)
```

**Algorithm 1:** (Cycle & Slice)

Most pythonic way is using the functions, `islice` and `cycle` from the `itertools` module offcourse:

- Cycle through / Repeat the list infinitely (`cycle` function)
- Slice out / Pick the desired elements using start/stop indices from the repeated list (`slice` function)

Code:

```
from itertools import cycle, islice 
desired = list( islice( cycle( lst), i+1, i+1+x))
```

**Algorithm 2:** (Loop & Modulo Indexing)

A more traditional way would be:

- Loop through the list `x` no. of times starting after the matched index, `i+1`
- Cycle through the list elements using `modulo` indexing

Code:

```
desired = [ lst[ j%n] for j in range(i+1, i+1+x)]
```

**Algorithm 3 - Bad Implementations:** (Rotate & Repeat)

Many poor/ slow implementations are also possible e.g. using `numpy` functions, like `roll`, `tile`:

- Roll/ Rotate the `numpy` array so as to start it with the element at the matching index, `i`
- Tile / Repeat the array so as to increase its length more than the desired `x` no. of elements
- Pick `x` no. of elements

Code:

```
def nextx(lst,i,n,x):
    ll = np.array(lst)
    rll = np.roll(ll, n-i)
    trll = np.tile(rll, x%n+1)
    return list(trll[:x])
```

**Output:**

```
>>> nextx(lst,5,7,11)
['string6', 'string7', 'string1', 'string2', 'string3', 'string4', 'string5', 'string6', 'string7', 'string1', 'string2']
>>> nextx(lst,5,7,11) == [lst[j%len(lst)] for j in range(5,5+11)] == list(islice(cycle(lst),5,5+11))
True
```

**Timing:**

iPython line magic function `%timeit` shows that `Algorithm 1` is not surprisingly `~1.5 and ~11 times faster` than 2 and 3 respectively:

```
>>> %timeit list( islice( cycle( lst), 5, 5+11))
100000 loops, best of 3: 1.83 µs per loop

>>> %timeit [ lst[ j%len(lst)] for j in range(5, 5+11)] 
100000 loops, best of 3: 2.76 µs per loop

>>> %timeit nextx(lst,5,7,11)
10000 loops, best of 3: 20.6 µs per loop
```

**Conclusion:**

Using `itertools` is the Fastest and Slickest way to go whenever you can use `cycle`, `islice`, `count`, `repeat`, etc!

Answer (score 8):

You can use [`cycle` from `itertools`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle), maybe in combination with [`islice`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice) and [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate).

```
from itertools import cycle, islice

x = 11
text = "string5"
lst = ["string1", "string2", "string3", "string4", "string5", "string6", "string7"]
for i, elem in enumerate(lst):
    if text in elem:
        next11 = list(islice(cycle(lst), i+1, i+1+x))
        print(next11)
        print(len(next11))
```

Output:

```
['string6', 'string7', 'string1', 'string2', 'string3', 'string4', 'string5', 'string6', 'string7', 'string1', 'string2']
11
```

Comment: Good point using `itertools`. However, I would just use `lst.index(text)` to find out the starting position.

Comment: @spectras `index` would not work. He's not testing for equality, but whether `text` is _in_ `elem`. Also, there could be multiple matches.

Comment: Indeed, only given his sample I supposed the use of `in` instead of a comparison was a mistake in his code. Would be worth asking him. And if there are multiple matches, `index` returns the first one.

Comment: Upvoting anyway, because this answer is by far the most pythonic one.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this will help

```
>>> x = 11
>>> text = "string5"
>>> list = ["string1", "string2", "string3", "string4", "string5", "string6", "string7"]

>>> for i in range(len(list)):
        if text in list[i]:
            a=i+1;
            break;

>>> L = [list[i%len(list)] for i in range(a, a+x)]

>>> L
['string6', 'string7', 'string1', 'string2', 'string3', 'string4', 'string5', 'string6', 'string7',     'string1', 'string2']
```

Answer (score 1):

Was annoid not getting it, so here is a beautiful solution.. :P

```
>>> x = 11
>>> text = "string5"
>>> list = ["string1", "string2", "string3", "string4", "string5", "string6", "string7"]
>>> offset = list.index(text)
>>> list_len = len(list)
>>> for i in range(x):
>>>     print(list[(i+offset)%list_len])
```

It assumes that each string in the list is unique, else you can just set the offset.

Answer (score -1):

use a while-loop?

```
i = 0
n = 0
while 1:
  if i > len(list):
    i = 0
  if (k > x):
    break
  print(list[i])
  i += 1
  k += 1
```